# How come a keyword with 46 local monthly searches get 150 local monthly impressions?

Tags: analytics

I am doing a keyword analysis by correlating data between Google ANalytics and Google Adwords Keyword tool. So here is the confusion

I check the local monthly searches (Sweden) for "SEO Packages" using the adwords keyword tool and it shows: 46 monthly searches

Now I come back to GA and check the impressions for "SEO Packages" that we got from Sweden and the value is: 150 impressions.

So basically:
Local monthly searches in Sweden: 46
Monthly impression we got from Sweden: 150

How come we get 150 impressions out of only 150 searches?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have linked your Google Webmaster Tools and Google Analytics, and those are the impressions you are referring to. Google counts these each time you search. I've noticed this on sites which have unique names and once we begin testing if it's cached and indexed those appear as impressions. I believe GWT is more accurate than their keyword tool. You can test this buy running a very specific search which will make your website appear in the top 100 and then check the impressions in webmaster tools the next day and you should see it. Run the same search and it'll count another impression.